# ''TabItem' ControlTemplate TargetType does not match templated type 'TabControl'.'

Tags: wpf

I am new to WPF and I have the following error when trying to open the form where my tabcontrol lives:

'TabItem' ControlTemplate TargetType does not match templated type 'TabControl'.

this is my tabcontrol in the Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <TabControl Style="{DynamicResource MyTabControl}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" BorderThickness="0" 
                Height="549" Margin="10,10,0,0" Background="LightGray"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="509">


        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

</Grid>
```

and this is the style I have defined for it:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style  x:Key="MyTabControl" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" 
                            BorderBrush="Gainsboro" 
                            CornerRadius="4,4,0,0" Margin="2,0">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                  ContentSource="Header"
                                                  Margin="10,2"/>

                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

what can be problem?

Comment: As the error message clearly says, `TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}"` isn't valid for the ControlTemplate of a TabControl. Did you perhaps intend to write an ItemContainerStyle?

Comment: I only want to change the appearance of tabitem headers...

Comment: Change the Style's TargetType to `TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}"` and apply the Style by `ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MyTabControl}"`

Comment: ItemContainerStyle solved my problem. thank you.. If you write the answer below I will mark it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to set a TabItem's ControlTemplate via a Style, the Style must use `TabItem` instead of `TabControl` as its TargetType:

```
<Style x:Key="MyTabItemStyle" TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                ...
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In addition to that, the Style has to be applied to the TabControl's `ItemContainerStyle` instead of its `Style`:

```
<TabControl ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource MyTabItemStyle}" ...>
    ...
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, the target type is wrong.
Change this

```
<Style  x:Key="MyTabControl" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
```

to

```
<Style x:Key="TabItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
```

You can do this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TabItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" 
                    BorderBrush="Gainsboro" 
                    CornerRadius="4,4,0,0" Margin="2,0">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            ContentSource="Header"
                                            Margin="10,2"/>

                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
```

and use

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="TabItem1" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle1}">                
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="TabItem2" Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle1}">                
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

WIll produce this output:

[image: Screenshot]